# Cost of list functions in Python

Tags: python, performance, list

Based on [this older thread](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/101848-list-implementation), it looks like the cost of list functions in Python is:

- Random access: O(1)
- Insertion/deletion to front: O(n)
- Insertion/deletion to back: O(1)

Can anyone confirm whether this is still true in Python 2.6/3.x?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3128/#motivation). It's a PEP for a different kind of list. The version specified is 2.6/3.0.

Append (insertion to back) is `O(1)`, while insertion (everywhere else) is `O(n)`.  So **yes**, it looks like this is still true.

```
Operation...Complexity
Copy........O(n) 
Append......O(1)
Insert......O(n) 
Get Item....O(1)
Set Item....O(1)
Del Item....O(n) 
Iteration...O(n)
Get Slice...O(k)
Del Slice...O(n)
Set Slice...O(n+k)
Extend......O(k) 
Sort........O(n log n)
Multiply....O(nk)
```

Comment: Thanks Ryeguy—appreciate it.  Also from the TimeComplexity doc referenced by kaizer.se:

x in s........... O(n)
min(s), max(x)... O(n)

Comment: @ryeguy: Surprised to see that insert and delete are O(n) operations.  Isn't the whole point of a list data structure to reduce the time complexity of insert and delete to O(1)?  From the above, it seems more like the underlying data structure is an array.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @AKE see [array list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_list). There are tradeoffs in different implementations of data structures. In your typical O(1) insert/delete list you often have Get Item as O(n).

Comment: @MikeS: Yes, I see.  Subsequent to asking the question, I found that processor architecture also makes a different the choice of actual implementation.  For example, processors with cache memory behaviour in which every memory access pulls back a cache line with adjacent memory, means that in fact the O(n) insert/deletes from adjacent memory addresses held in cache can actually be faster than an O(1) memory access from locations spread randomly in memory.

Comment: What is the complexity to check if an integer exists in a list of numbers ? >>> 3 in lis

Comment: It is O(n) because you are searching over all the elements of list.

Answer (score 9):

Python 3 is mostly an evolutionary change, no big changes in the datastructures and their complexities.

The canonical source for Python collections is [TimeComplexity](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) on the Wiki.

Answer (score 4):

That's correct, inserting in front forces a move of all the elements to make place.

`collections.deque` offers similar functionality, but is optimized for insertion on both sides.

Comment: Does that mean that the underlying data structure is an array?  If it were a list, an insert anywhere, including at the front, should be an O(1) operations, right?

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is old, but I recently did a little test myself. The complexity of list.insert() appears to be O(n)

[image: Cost of Insertion. Ignore left plot]

Code:

```
'''
Independent Study, Timing insertion list method in python
'''
import time

def make_list_of_size(n):
    ret_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        ret_list.append(n)
    return ret_list

#Estimate overhead of timing loop
def get_overhead(niters):
    '''
    Returns the time it takes to iterate a for loop niter times
    '''
    tic = time.time()
    for i in range(niters):
        pass #Just blindly iterate, niter times
    toc = time.time()
    overhead = toc-tic
    return overhead

def tictoc_midpoint_insertion(list_size_initial, list_size_final, niters,file):
    overhead = get_overhead(niters)
    list_size = list_size_initial
    #insertion_pt = list_size//2 #<------- INSERTION POINT ASSIGMNET LOCATION 1
    #insertion_pt = 0 #<--------------- INSERTION POINT ASSIGNMENT LOCATION 4 (insert at beginning)
    delta = 100
    while list_size <= list_size_final:
        #insertion_pt = list_size//2 #<----------- INSERTION POINT ASSIGNMENT LOCATION 2
        x = make_list_of_size(list_size)
        tic = time.time()
        for i in range(niters):
            insertion_pt = len(x)//2 #<------------- INSERTION POINT ASSIGNMENT LOCATION 3
            #insertion_pt = len(x) #<------------- INSERTION POINT ASSIGN LOC 5 insert at true end
            x.insert(insertion_pt,0)
        toc = time.time()
        cost_per_iter = (toc-tic)/niters #overall time cost per iteration
        cost_per_iter_no_overhead = (toc - tic - overhead)/niters #the fraction of time/iteration, #without overhead cost of pure iteration                                              
        print("list size = {:d}, cost without overhead = {:f} sec/iter".format(list_size,cost_per_iter_no_overhead))
        file.write(str(list_size)+','+str(cost_per_iter_no_overhead)+'\n')
        if list_size >= 10*delta:
            delta *= 10
        list_size += delta

def main():
    fname = input()
    file = open(fname,'w')
    niters = 10000
    tictoc_midpoint_insertion(100,10000000,niters,file)
    file.close()

main()
```

See 5 positions where insertion can be done. Cost is of course a function of how large the list is, and how close you are to the beginning of the list (i.e. how many memory locations have to be re-organized)

Ignore left image of plot

Answer (score 2):

Fwiw, there is a faster (for some ops... insert is O(log n)) [list implementation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3128/) called BList if you need it.  [BList](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/)