# Sieve of Eratosthenes speed differences

Tags: python, python-2.7, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Why is the first one so much faster than the second? I get that storing the primes as 1s and 0s is simpler, but the speed increase is ridiculous. And at the end, it still goes through a list 2 million items long, how is that even remotely possible in the 1s it takes to compile?

```
def prime_sieve(limit):
    primes = [1 for x in xrange(limit)]
    primes[0] = 0
    primes[1] = 0
    imax = int(math.sqrt(limit) + 1)

    i = 2
    while (i < imax):
        j = i + i
        while j < limit:
            primes[j] = 0
            j += i
        while True:
            i += 1
            if primes[i] == 1:
                break
    return primes

s = prime_sieve(2000000)
print(sum(i for i in xrange(len(s)) if s[i] == 1))
-----------------------------------------------------------
def sieve(max):
    primes = range(2, max+1)
    for i in primes:
        j = 2
        while i * j <= primes[-1]:
            if i * j in primes:
                primes.remove(i*j)
                j += 1
    return primes

count = 0
for x in sieve(2000000):
    count += x
print count
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Add a `print i` in both outermost loops and run both functions for some small input, say `100`. See what numbers are tested in both functions!

Comment: there's an error in the code (except for the obvious wrong indentation inside the function `sieve`): 6th line from the bottom should be un-indented back at the equal level with the `if` above it.

Answer (score 6):

Because when you remove stuff you can't use [direct addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) anymore. Direct addressing is the key to the sieve of Eratosthenes's speed (similar to the [integer sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sorting)'s speed advantage over the comparison-based sorting).

In your first code, `primes[j] = 0` is an O(1) operation. But in the second, `primes.remove(i*j)` is an O(n) operation (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521784/cost-of-list-functions-in-python)).

You also start enumerating the multiples of `i` at `2*i` instead of `i^2`. It's much less of a problem though compared with the above.

To properly compare algorithmic speed, **always compare [empirical orders of growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth)**. Here are [the results](http://ideone.com/oq8mHy):

```
# First code:
# --i+i--                                 # --i*i--
#   N       n    time-space   ~ n^        #    N     n     time-space   ~ n^
#  10k     1229  0.02s-7.9M               #
#  2mln  148933  1.13s-7.9M               #  2mln  148933  1.12s-7.9M  
#  4mln  283146  2.30s-7.9M  n^1.11       #  4mln  283146  2.25s-7.9M  n^1.09
#  8mln  539777  4.58s-7.9M  n^1.07       #  8mln  539777  4.38s-7.9M  n^1.03
# 16mln 1031130  9.12s-7.9M  n^1.06       # 16mln 1031130  8.82s-7.9M  n^1.08

# Second code:
# --j=2--                                 # --j=i--
#   5k      669  0.35s-7.9M               #   5k      669  0.28s-7.9M
#  10k     1229  1.37s-7.9M  n^2.24       #  10k     1229  1.16s-7.9M  n^2.34
#  20k     2262  5.21s-7.9M  n^2.19       #  20k     2262  4.66s-7.9M  n^2.28
#  30k     3245 11.76s-7.9M  n^2.26       #  30k     3245 11.24s-7.9M  n^2.44
```

`N` is upper limit, and `n` - number of primes below it. The exponents are of course approximate, and their deltas are not measured, but they do give us a general picture. A quadratic (or worse) algorithm is surely much different from the linearithmic one.